# How do i print the results of a method into an existing text file?

Tags: java, file, methods, printing

I'm working on a task where the results of a method will print into an existing text file. How do I get this method to print into the file, instead of the main when getDivisors() is called in the main? In the main method, I also ask the user for input of a name and it will create a .txt file with numbers inside the file.

```
public static void getDivisors(double n) 
{ 
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) 
        if (n%i==0) 
            System.out.println(i+" ");
            System.out.println("The divisors for " + n + " are" + " listed above"); 
            System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileWriter like so:

```
try {
    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0){
            myWriter.write(i + " ");
            myWriter.write("The divisors for " + n + " are" + " listed above");
            myWriter.write(" ");
        }
    myWriter.close();
} catch (IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

We can turn on append mode by specifying `true` as the second argument in the constructor. This will append the text to the file, rather than deleting everything and rewriting.

For good practice, we will catch an `IOException`, since that's the only error that a FileWriter throws.